# SQL Get last rows of different enum values

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have a table with one "type"-column, this column is a enum with eight possibilities. I now want to query the last row of each enum value - so if I'm looking for four of the eight possible values, I want four rows with each one of the enums.

Any ideas?

Edit examples:
following enum: type=("example1","ex2","ex3")
Each row has a type and a timestamp
I'd like to have the last timestamp of every type.

Sample Data:
example 1 - 7:13,
ex2 - 8:14,
example 1 - 9:17,
ex3 - 6:13

Wished Result:
example 1 - 9:17,
ex2 - 8:14

Dialect is MySQL. Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Could you include a few rows of sample data?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful as well.

Comment: Define "last". According to what order? Also, please specify database "dialect" (Oracle, MS SQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...) because some have features making such a query easier, e.g. using windowing functions.

Comment: Thanks - I implemented your suggestions - hope its clearer now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

If your table `MyTable` has an "enum" column named `EnumColumn`, and you want last row for each value in a list of given enum values (`Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`), where "last" is defined by a `DateColumn`, and you're using a database that supports *windowing functions* (e.g. [MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql), [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html)), you can do it like this:

```sql
SELECT Column1, EnumColumn, Column3, DateColumn, Column5
  FROM ( SELECT Column1, EnumColumn, Column3, DateColumn, Column5
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY EnumColumn
                                    ORDER BY DateColumn DESC ) AS ROW_NUM
           FROM MyTable
          WHERE EnumColumn IN ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz')
       ) x
 WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Comment: Thank but i'm using MySQL - I updated my question too.